# Can NSwag invoke a custom Swagger generator?

Tags: swagger-2.0, nswag

Is there a way to specify a custom [`ISwaggerGenerator`](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.SwaggerGeneration/ISwaggerGenerator.cs) or invoke some method or program to produce the output swagger spec in the `swaggerGenerator` section of `nswag.json`?

The standard `fromSwagger` generator seems to work with only an output path, so as a last resort, I may use an [exec task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2017) to create the file named there. But it would seem less hacky to specify my generator directly in `nswag.json`.

```
"swaggerGenerator": {
    "fromSwagger": {
        "output": "swagger.json"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the input can be a file/url or one of NSwag’s Swagger generators (use NSwagStudio to see the available inputs).